# Why can't I drop a table in Excel via ODBC?

Tags: excel, odbc, vba

I am using ODBC to connect to Excel via my DSN which has a default worksheet configured.

I can create pages in the worksheet via the create table command like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable( c VARCHAR(8) )
```

However when I use the drop table command like this:

```
DROP TABLE testtable
```

The Execute function returns a success value but the sheet is not deleted.  The column name has been removed but that is all.

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the Excel ODBC driver - the `DROP` statement will clear the worksheet, but not delete it.